# Combinar Arreglos con Enum

Tags: c++, array, enum

tengo una enumeración con los meses, algo así

```
enum Meses {
 Enero,
 Febrero,
 [...],
 Diciembre };
```

Tengo un arreglo, donde almaceno datos enteros. Ahora, lo que necesito hacer es algo como

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // Donde n es el numero de datos en el arreglo
{
  if (Arreglo[i] >= 12) // Mayor que 12, ya que diciembre tendrá valor 11
     cout << "Error";
  else
     cout << Meses[Arreglo[i]] << endl;
}
```

Por si no se entiende, lo que quiero hacer, es que dado el valor entero en el arreglo, mostrar el dato correspondiente en la enumeración `Meses`.

¿Se podrá hacer algo así?

Comment: @abulafia Deberías ponerlo como respuesta :-)

Comment: @Trauma Hecho. Borro el comentario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No directamente. La solución más sencilla sería que tuvieras un array de cadenas con los nombres de los meses:

```
char *NombresMeses[] = {
     "Enero", "Febrero", ...
};
```

y usaras índices dentro de ese array para obtener los nombres:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // Donde n es el numero de datos en el arreglo
{
  if (Arreglo[i] >= 12) // Mayor que 12, ya que diciembre tendrá valor 11
     cout << "Error";
  else
     cout << NombresMeses[Arreglo[i]] << endl;
}
```

El `Enum` realmente no lo necesitas para esto, pero puede ser conveniente mantenerlo por si quieres comparar números con meses. Siempre quedará más legible algo como:

```
if (Arreglo[i] == Enero) ...
```

frente a:

```
if (Arreglo[i] == 0) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

No existen mecanismos *estandar* para convertir un enumerado en una cadena... sin embargo es posible conseguir ese efecto.

Lo primero es crear un archivo nuevo, por ejemplo `Meses.inc` con un contenido tal que:

```
MES(Enero)
MES(Febrero)
MES(Marzo)
MES(Abril)
MES(Mayo)
MES(Junio)
MES(Julio)
MES(Agosto)
MES(Septiembre)
MES(Octubre)
MES(Noviembre)
MES(Diciembre)
```

Este archivo será la base que nos permitirá generar de forma automática todo el código que necesitamos. Solo necesitamos redefinir la macro `MES` para que nos genere el código que necesitamos en cada momento. Así, para rellenar el enumerado:

```
enum Meses
{
  #define MES(x) x,
  #include "Meses.inc"
  #undef MES
};
```

Con esto conseguimos que el preprocesador genere un código tal que:

```
enum Meses
{
  Enero,
  Febrero,
  Marzo,
  // ...
};
```

Mientras que para tener una función que nos permita convertir los valores del enumerado en cadena:

```
std::string MesToString(Meses mes)
{
  switch(mes)
  {
    #define MES(x) case x: return #x;
    #include "Meses.inc"
    #undef MES
  }

  return "";
}
```

Las posibilidades son infinitas y, lo mejor de todo, es que en el archivo `meses.inc` podemos añadir información adicional... por ejemplo texto en distintos idiomas:

```
MES(Enero,January)
MES(Febrero,February)
MES(Marzo,March)
MES(Abril,April)
MES(Mayo,May)
MES(Junio,June)
MES(Julio,July)
MES(Agosto,August)
MES(Septiembre,September)
MES(Octubre,October)
MES(Noviembre,November)
MES(Diciembre,December)
```

Ahora, para generar el enumerado solo nos interesa el primer parámetro:

```
enum Meses
{
  #define MES(x,y) x,
  #include "Meses.inc"
  #undef MES
};
```

Y para convertir a *string*:

```
std::string MesToString(Meses mes,bool ingles)
{
  switch(mes)
  {
    #define MES(x,y) case x: return ingles ? #y : #x;
    #include "Meses.inc"
    #undef MES
  }

  return "";
}
```

La parte mala de usar este mecanismo es que los IDEs, no van a poder darnos información sobre los valores del enumerado (*intellisense*), pero a cambio disponemos de un mecanismo muy potente y versátil que nos evita escribir un buen número de líneas de código. El tiempo de compilación también será sensiblemente mayor.